# converting list into dictionary using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a list -created from a dataframe- to a dictionary in python. I am fairly new to this area of python, so if I have done something wrong please point it out.

Lets suppose I have a list: 
`a = [['Robert'], ['Tommy'], ['Joe'], ['Will']]`

The key is supposed to be 'Name', and the value as the string in the list.

I have tried:
`dct = {'Name': a[i] for i in range(len(a))}`

I would end up getting:
`{'Name': ['Will']}`
Not sure if this is necessary, but I only got the last value in the list. Please can anyone point out what is going wrong here.

Comment: The keys in a dictionary have to be unique.

Comment: What do you want the resulting dictionary to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because it's repeatedly assigning a new value to the key `'Name'` in that dictionary. The dictionary comprehension that you've written behaves the same as:

```
dct = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    dct['Name'] = a[i]
```

So that's why afterwards you end up with a dictionary that has one key in it with the last value.

Answer (score 0):

If this can work!

```
dct = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    dct['Name'] = a
print dct
```

Comment: The `for` loop is unnecessary, it's doing the same thing each time. It can be simplified to `dct = {'Name': a}`, which may actually be what they were asking for.

Comment: Ohh, Thanks @mkrieger1